# GWT grid table tab-ing order

Tags: java, gwt, tabs

I have a GWT table, created using grid. Currently if I iterate through cells using tab, it goes in row-wise fashion. Is there any way to make tables in GWT iterable in column-wise order.

Below are images of current and of expected TAB order in my GWT table.

Current behavior:

[image]

Wanted behavior:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

One not so elegant solution would be to used method setTabIndex on the content of each cell.

```
cellContent.setTabIndex(index++);
```

Comment: Yes, that would work. However, I would also need to set tab index to all other elements of the page, which would be quite awful. Furthermore each new element that is added to the page will need to have tab index set.

Comment: You can use getTabIndex of the element right before the table and continue from there. I will update my answer to reflect this

Comment: I will still have to set all the elements after the table as well. Note that the page layout is quite complex and contains several menus, header, footer etc.

Comment: You're right! But i doubt that there is another way :/

Comment: I see your point, but *no one* is using tabs to navigate from the data grid to the element after the data grid - or vice versa. I suggest that you start your index in the DataGrid from 1000 (or 10,000) and increment it. A user will be able to use a tab inside a DataGrid, and it will not interfere with tab order for other elements on the page.